# ROWNUM MYSQL giving 1 as row numbers

Tags: mysql, sql, rownum

I am running following query in mysql and it is giving me just "1" as row_num instead of auto incrementing it. Can anyone please guide me what is wrong

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY DISEASEIDPK) AS row_num,COUNT(*) PATIENTSAVAILABLE, DISEASEIDPK, 
(Select DISEASENAME from doctorsoncallschema.diseases d where d.DISEASEIDPK = doctorsoncallschema.patients.DISEASEIDPK) as DISEASENAME
FROM doctorsoncallschema.patients  
GROUP BY DISEASEIDPK ORDER BY row_num ASC;
```

Result

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to *order* using the `DISEASEIDPK` column, rather than partitioning by it.  If so, then use:

```sql
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DISEASEIDPK) AS row_num
```

Using `PARTITION BY DISEASEIDPK` means that every record having the same `DISEASEIDPK` value will be assigned the same row number.